# Django, multiple databases with raw sql. How to choose db?

Tags: django, database

I have a Django project that utilizes multiple databases. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

I perform a lot of raw queries like this:

```
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute("select * from my_table")
  ....
  transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

How can I specify which database to use?

Comment: Have you tried `transaction.commit_unless_managed(using = 'database_entry')`?

Comment: Nobody has linked to the actual documentation, which is very clear: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: the accepted solution worked for me, and then I ran into issues with breaking unit tests... this fixed the issue, but ran quite slowly https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/advanced/#tests-and-multiple-databases… (I ultimately ended up using app config to specify which database to use per env)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Refer django docs on [executing custom query directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly). Specify database in your connection as given below:

```
from django.db import connections
cursor = connections['db_alias'].cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from my_table")
data = cursor.fetchall()
for row in data:
    print(data)
```

And then commit using

```
from django.db import transaction
transaction.commit_unless_managed(using='db_alias')
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete. It doesn't shown an example of at least one SQL query with the cursor, how the transaction will work, and from where did you got that transaction object. @arulmr

Answer (score 0):

try this may be it should works.

```
from django.db import connections
cursor = connections[’my_db_name’].cursor()
# Your code here...
transaction.commit_unless_managed(using=’my_db_name’)
```