# How to select database in django db collection custom query?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, psql

I have two databases in my django application. One is default and another is secondary. When I tried the following code it always returns data from the default database.

> from django.db import connection
>
> def my_custom_sql(self):
>
> cursor = connection.cursor()
>
> cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts_account where id=%s",
>   [self.id])
>
> row = cursor.fetchall()
>
> return row

I want to execute the query in second database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django, multiple databases with raw sql. How to choose db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223971/django-multiple-databases-with-raw-sql-how-to-choose-db)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django multiple and dynamic databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585373/django-multiple-and-dynamic-databases)

Comment: the accepted solution worked for me, and then I ran into issues with breaking unit tests... 
this fixed the issue, but ran quite slowly https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/advanced/#tests-and-multiple-databases
(I ultimately ended up using app config to specify which database to use per env)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to

```
from django.db import connections
```

instead of

```
from django.db import connection
```

and use your database alias as below:

```
cursor = connections['secondry_db'].cursor()
```