# Multiple Django Database Connection

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm using django 2.0. I need to execute a large sql query on another database rather than default, is it possible to specify the database name (that is defined in settings.py) when importing connection from django.db??

PS: No routers suggestions

Comment: Ok, found in another post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223971/django-multiple-databases-with-raw-sql-how-to-choose-db) the answer by arulmr. The thing is to import connections instead of connection using the database name as key.

Comment: Theres no need to add the import code, isn't nothing complex. After the link I'm already clearly explaining what is all about. ;)