# Django: apply filter on field of related model which is in another database

Tags: python, django

I've two tables in two database, say `Policy` in DB_A and `Quote` in DB_B.

`Policy` has a field `result_reference` which is the id of `Quote` table in DB_B

**policy in DB_A**

```
class Policy(models.Model):
    result_reference = models.IntegerField()
    policy_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

**Quote in DB_B**

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    quote_type = models.IntegerField()
    policy_type = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    policy_premium = models.IntegerField()
```

The policy type can be `S` for Single and `M` for Multiple
I want to get the policies with policy date after 30 days along with `policy_type=M`

What I've tried

```
import datetime
start_date = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(30)
p = Policy.objects.using(default_database).filter(policy_date__gte=start_date)
```

But this returns policies that have `policy_type` `S` and `M`. How can I filter it for policy type `M`?

Comment: You can user raw sql queries.
There is a sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18224123/7659834)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you well, you can try:
take a list of the `quotes` with type `M` and filter the `Policy` by this list using `in`, and of cause you should apply valid `using` for each query.

```
m_quotes = Quote.objects.filter(policy_type='M').values_list('pk', flat=True)
m_quotes = list(m_quotes)
p = Policy.objects.using(default_database).filter(result_reference__in=m_quotes)
```

Comment: in m_quotes, since we are not mentioning `using()` , I'm assuming it is taking the default database. which is as good as mentioning `using(default_database)`. When i tried m_quotes query with `using(DB_B)` and p query with `using(DB_A)` , i get an error stating `Force the inner query to be evaluated using `list(inner_query)`